# How to specify a file as downloadable in AsciiDoc

Tags: html, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am generating html files from a AsciiDoc file.my requirement is to make a file as downloadable in generated html.

for example: below html code will make `file1.txt` as downloadable

```
 <a href="/text_files/file1.txt" download>
```

how do i specify `file1.txt` as downloadable in my AsciiDoc file.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently not supported by Asciidoctor out of the box, see https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor/issues/1781

Two options (out of probably many other) I see:

- Post-processing the HTML or extending Asciidoctor for example by creating your own template or output format.
- Instructing the web server you use to send headers that force the browser to provide it as a download to the user (like `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=file1.txt`) ... depending on your web server and the configuration you choose, this could be triggered by a query parameter.